# Function executes twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't understand why my function **returnSlidesReducer()** executes twice.
I'm using Redux.

My reducer file ***slides.js*** is (reads json file and returns data to a store):

```js
import jsonFile from '../sliderContent.json';

const returnSlidesReducer = (slidesContent) => {
  console.log(slidesContent);
  return slidesContent;
}

returnSlidesReducer(jsonFile);

export default returnSlidesReducer;
```

And my ***index.js***:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {
  createStore
} from 'redux';
//import allReducers from './reducers';
import SlidesReducer from './reducers/slides';

const store = createStore(SlidesReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In console I get:

1. {slider:Array(3)}
2. undefined

And because of this in a store I get *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

See the reducer from the example todo app in `Redux` doc:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return state.concat([action.text])
    default:
      return state
  }
 }

let store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'])
```

You don't need to explicitly call your reducer function like you do.

If you want to use the json object as the initial state, you can pass it as the second argument to `createStore(..)`

```
createStore(returnSlidesReducer, jsonFile);
```

On a side note, your reducer function isn't of the standard redux reducer form. I recommend following [the official `Redux` example](https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list).